# How to open SSRS report anonymously in sharepoint integrated mode?

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services, anonymous-authentication

We have deployed one ssrs report on sharepoint server. For accessing that report anonymously, we have configured anonymous access on reports document library.

But the following error is showing on report page while accessing that report,

```
The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' are insufficient for performing this operation. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' are insufficient for performing this operation.
```

After searching on google, The [MSDN forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/c79f12a9-23f0-446b-9af1-49f1c7a1692b/the-permissions-granted-to-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon-are-insufficient-for-performing-this?forum=sqlreportingservices) saying that, **SSRS does not support anonymous access.**

Is there any OOTB way, Custom webpart, third party webpart OR any other workaround to access report anonymously? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are using SharePoint integrated mode, it limits your options but I’m not certain.

If you used native mode, I think you can create a custom authentication provider using the MS example for Forms Auth as a model.

Another option, and again not sure how Integrated mode comes into play, but you could create a custom web part using the ASP.NET Report Viewer web control and handle the authentication in your code.